# Whether Subset of a Power Set is a Lattice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

$A=$ countably infinite set
$p(A)=$ power set of $A$
$p(A)$ is uncountably infinite

I have this question as book i am using explicitly mentioned it as A:finite set

now, poset $(P(A)$,**subset**) is it a lattice?

I know what a lattice is and according to definition any partial order relation on  uncountably infinite set where each element has a LUB,GLB should be counted as a lattice.

Comment: The question is not asking about a _subset of a power set_. It asks whether the power set _itself_ is a lattice when ordered by the subset relation.

Comment: Also, I find it quite unlikely that the definition of a "lattice" you have is restricted to work with uncountably infinite sets. Where do you have that definition from? Can you quote it exactly here?

Comment: It is always best in mathematics to not try to paraphrase your understanding, or if you do paraphrase, include the original, as well, so we can help you understand the original text. For example, in any poset, every single element has a least upper bound - itself. A lattice requires every pair of elements to have a least upper and greatest lower bound. A complete lattice requires any subset of elements to have a GLB and LUB.

Comment: See [Lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) : the example of  the Hasse diagram of the subset of a (finite) set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every set $X$ the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ together with the subset relation $\subseteq$ forms a complete lattice. I explained this recently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599247/in-borel-cantelli-lemma-what-is-the-limit-superior/1599319#1599319) as part of another answer.